# How do I display current page on wp_nav_menu on a mobile device for WordPress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm trying to fix a WordPress website that does not display the current page on the wp_nav_menu for mobile devices. I know where the wp_nav_menu is located (header.php). How can I have the drop down menu on mobile devices display the current page the the user is on? The website is [avantirecruiters.com](http://avantirecruiters.com).
I've seen the question about adding a filter and a function special_nav_class, but I'm still confused on how implement the current page to the menu for a mobile device.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26789439/1032472

Comment: I appreciate the link. I've actually seen that question before. I"m still confused on how to apply this to the drop menu that I have, and whether or not it would solve my problem.

Comment: Check your Javascript code or css where it set `selected="selected"` attribute in `<option value="http://avantirecruiters.com/contact-2/" selected="selected">Contact</option>`. It is currently defaulted to the last items in the `<select><option>...</option></select>` item when it is in mobile mode. Can't help you directly as you didn't post the code, but this should give you the general direction.

Comment: This is through WordPress, and as far as I can tell I don't have access to any Javascript files, but I do have access to style.css, and maybe writing new Javascript for a particular element in script tags. I looked for what you suggested and I wasn't able to find it.