# Wordpress: Highlight Active/ Selected Menu Item CSS/PHP

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The WordPress theme I'm currently using, shows a blue bar below the menu items when the mouse hovers over the specific items. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVJDI.png). I want the bar to appear when one of the selected menu item is active or is the active page. Like that of [Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI26j.jpg).

How do I modify the CSS and PHP to suit my needs?
I have these resources: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789438/how-to-add-active-class-to-wp-nav-menu-current-menu-item-simple-way),[#2](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/418834/show-active-tab-in-menu#), [#3](https://www.billerickson.net/customize-which-menu-item-is-marked-active/)

My menu items consist of category links and single page link.